# PHP allowing and disallowing access to page via direct access or link?

Tags: php

Is there an actual way to detect if the page was created or clicked on by a specific link in PHP? For example. I'm trying to create an access code. The access code is emailed to a user. The page isn't really secure so I want to check if the page was loaded or clicked on by a link from the email or accessed directly. If the page that is loaded was clicked on by a link from the email, then allow access, if the page was accessed directly, then echo an error.

Now I know that emails normally create new tabs or new windows. I was wondering if that's even possible for PHP to do such a function.

I've tried with the code below, but it seems to only be allowing clicked links within the accessed website. External links doesn't work for this code.

```
    <?
    $refering = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if($refering['host'] == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
        echo "Access Granted"; 
    } else {
        echo "Access Denied";
    }
    ?>
```

I want to be clear. I'm not trying to create an access code or anything else. I'm just wondering if there's a way to allow email links to access a page.

Comment: No. The only advice I would give would be to create a suitably long and hard-to-guess access code

Comment: you have to use access codes via GET (tokens you distribute to whom in need of such links)

Comment: @Gar I already have an access code thought up and it's already working. The only concern I'm having is what if someone smart comes along and types in a random code along with the username? Then that person can basically do an SQL injection as they may. The reason why I want to do what I was explaining is because in fantasy, to me that is the most secure and safest way to approach this.

Comment: @JohnFurry i see your point, and no, there is no fully safe way doing it without a full auth scheme, as the full HTTP header can be forged by a malicious user, and any hash function is always prone to be found.

Comment: Thanks. Well my 2nd thought would be if this type of scenario doesn't work. I can try to insert the access code into a row along with the user's username and when they get the email and they click the link, they get redirected back to a success page. If the access code doesn't seem to exist in the row or their username doesn't exist in the row, then redirect to an error page telling them something went wrong.